# How to access Value from hidden input tag in cypress

Tags: input, cypress, dropdown, hidden

This is a dropdown and by default value is "False".

The dropdown value changes in hidden input tag only after selecting true.

```html
<div class="dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper dx-selectbox-container" xpath="1">
<input type="hidden" value="False">.
```

How do I assert this element should contain "False" by default

```js
cy.get('.dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper.dx-selectbox-container')
  .should('have.value','False')
```

But it is not accessing this value.

Expecting to be able to assert that by default the value is "False".

Comment: Can you provide the associated HTML with this test? What specific error message are you receiving from Cypress?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the `input` element tag into the selector

```js
cy.get('.dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper.dx-selectbox-container input')
  .should('have.value','False')
```

or "find" the input like this

```js
cy.get('.dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper.dx-selectbox-container')
  .find('input[type="hidden"]')
  .should('have.value','False')
```